# How to change the order of columns in CSS template to put important content first?

Tags: css, templates, css-float

I got a 3-column CSS template with columns tertiaryContent (right), primaryContent (middle) and secondaryContent (left). When I use Lynx to "see what robots see", the right column appears first because it's first in the order in index.php and in CSS, totally ruining my SEO. Even on SERPs, the text from the right column is shown below the link.

This is what I got in index.php:

```
    <div id="outer">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="tertiaryContent">
    </div>
    <div id="primaryContentContainer">
    <div id="primaryContent">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondaryContent">
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    </div>
```

And this is what I got in the default.css file:

```
    #outer {padding: 0em; margin: 0em; width: 100%;}
    #header {position: relative; height: 10px;}
    #primaryContentContainer {float: right; margin: 0em -15em 0em -19em; width: 100%;}
    #primaryContent {margin: 0em 15em 0em 15em; padding: 0em 0em 1.5em 4.25em;}
    #secondaryContent {position: relative; float: left; width: 15em; padding: 0 0em 1.5em 1em;}
    #secondaryContent .xbg {position: absolute; right: 0em; bottom: -64px; height: 64px; width: 128px;}
    #tertiaryContent {position: relative; float: right; width: 16em; margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em; padding: 0em 1em 0em 0em;}
    #tertiaryContent .xbg {position: absolute; left: 0em; bottom: -64px; height: 64px; width: 128px;}
```

My question is - how do I change this code to keep the same layout, but to show primaryContent first in order, so that it's #1 when reading the text version of the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With absolute positioning you can easily move blocks around regardless of how they appear in markup.

[Simplfied Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sqxAe)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="primary content">one</div>
<div class="secondary content">two</div>
<div class="tertiary content">three</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{width:600px; position:relative; margin:0 auto;}
.content{width:200px; height: 500px; position: absolute; top:0;}
.primary {background: salmon; left:200px;}
.secondary{background: lightblue; left: 400px; }
.tertiary{background: goldenrod;}
```